# Django Rest Framework Get a JSON object in the request and parse in ListCreateAPIView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-request

I'm working on a project with Django Rest Framework in which I need to make a post request in which I need to pass a JSON object against a TextField along with the other fields, How can I pass a JSON object like this:

```
{
"no_of_svc": 3,
  "svc1": {
    "name": "details",
    "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
    "versions": {
      "v1": {
        "name": "details-v1",
        "image": "example-details-v1"
      }
    },
    "port": {
      "port": 9080,
      "name": "http"
    }
  },
  "svc2": {
    "name": "ratings",
    "versions": {
      "v1": {
        "name": "ratings-v1",
        "image": "example-ratings-v1"
      },
      "v2": {
        "name": "ratings-v2",
        "image": "example-ratings-v2"
      },
      "port": {
        "port": 9080,
        "name": "http"
      }
    }
  },
  "svc3": {
    "name": "reviews",
    "versions": {
      "v1": {
        "name": "reviews-v1",
        "image": "example-reviews-v1",
        "containerPort": 9080
      },
      "v2": {
        "name": "reviews-v2",
        "image": "example-reviews-v2"
      },
      "port": {
        "port": 9080,
        "name": "http"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and later parse it in the **create** method of **generics.ListCreateAPIView** ?

Here's my model:

```
services = (
    ('Single', 'Single'),
    ('Multiple', 'Multiple'),
)


class DeploymentOnUserModel(models.Model):
    deployment_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, )
    credentials = models.TextField(blank=False)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    cluster_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    zone_region = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=services)
    configuration = models.TextField()
    routing = models.TextField()

def save(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.id and self.services == 'Multiple' and not self.routing and not self.configuration:
        raise ValidationError("You must have to provide routing for multiple services deployment.")
    super().save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: I don't undestand the relation between the json and the DeploymentOnUserModel model, how exactly do you what your json to be deserialized ?

Comment: You can convert your json to a string with json.dumps(your_json) but then you should use json.loads(your_field_with_json_string) each time when getting data from it.

Comment: Hi @ElioMaisonneuve, actually, I have a textField in my model, for this field user will need to pass a JSON object.

Comment: Hi @AlexK., then how can I get values for various keys in JSON object e.g values for ** no_of_svc** ?

Comment: @AbdulRehman that's how you write json in a TextField: model_obj.configuration = json.dumps(your_json) (do not forget to save model object after this) and that's how you get data from it: configuration = json.loads(model_obj.configuration) (you get dict from json) and no_of_svc = configuration['no_of_svc'] (it's a dict now - just work with it like with regular dict).

Comment: Hi @AlexK., I need to pass post payload via a rest request, how can I pass a payload like this `{
  "deployment_name": "first_deployment",
  "credentials":{"test_key":"test_value"},
  "project_name": "project_name",
  "project_id": "project_id",
  "cluster_name": "numpy",
  "zone_region": "europe-west1-d",
  "services": "Single",
  "configuration": "",
  "routing": ""
}`